# Why I can't click on this div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click on the x inside of the close div, I want the background to change to white.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="list-item list-item-active">
    <div class="close">x</div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-item').live('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('list-item-active'))
            $(this).addClass('list-item-active');
    });
    $('.list-item .close').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('list-item-active');
    });
});
```

This is the css:

```
.list-item {width:100px;height:100px;background:#fff}
.list-item-active {background:#ccc}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JMeff/

Comment: Please make sure your question makes sense on its own.  jsFiddle, just like any site, can have its outages.

Comment: I would paste your code directly into this site, and then offer the jsFiddle link as a back-up (which, it's good to have an example, BTW).

Comment: when i add click event on element i cant add click event on elements inside that element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* click it, but the click *also* clicks the parent due to default event bubbling.  To get the effect you want, stop the bubble via [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('.list-item .close').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('list-item-active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JMeff/6/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-item').live('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('list-item-active'))
            $(this).addClass('list-item-active');
    });
    $('.list-item .close').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('list-item-active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note the new `return false`: otherwise the event will be caught by the `$('.list-item').live` instead of the one you want, the `$('.list-item .close').live`.

Comment: `return false` is overkill here, it's much better to use `event.stopPropagation()` which does *only* the bubble stop, not kill the event altogether.

Comment: You're right, Nick; I had read somewhere that `return false` worked with `live` but `event.stopPropagation()` did not, but indeed, testing it with the conveniently-provided fiddle shows you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't return false in the second event handler. Without a `return false;` the event will be handled be parent too which reads the class after you have removed it.